# C# Deployment - single executable, one click install?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I deploy a project?  I'd prefer it if it's just a single execute file with everything built into it.  Is this possible?  Or does it need to be installed with the DLLs staying as external files? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)

Comment: +1. ILMerge is the only option here, though there's no way to make it *truly* standalone (as the .NET runtime is required regardless of what you do)

Answer (score 1):

You may use Click once install (available in VS). Or check out Inno Setup http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php it's free and quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You have ClickOnce and Visual Studio Setup projects... Both are capable of collapsing your install with the Visual Studio Setup project being able to create a single Setup.exe for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer NSIS for deploying C# aps with a single setup executable

Edit: NSIS can be used to include the .NET runtime installer within the setup executable, or you can design it to download the .NET Framework if it is not present on the target machine.